# MySQL VarChar 255 and above

Tags: python, mysql, varchar

I am currently doing screen scraping and storing in to a MySQL database, I used some of my columns as `answer_content varchar(255) NOT NULL,`but the problem is some of the data is getting truncated, I was reading following [blog post](http://www.pythian.com/news/1353/max-varchar-size/).

But I am not really sure if that is the solution: What is the best solution to save the text without getting them truncated? I am not doing this on a server side and currently doing on a person laptop.

Comment: Use `TEXT`. Or a bigger `VARCHAR`, like `VARCHAR(10000)`.

Comment: Obviously a larger column count....why do you wonder that the text is truncsted when *you* specified 255 chars? Thinking helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change type to TEXT

Refer here:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/

Answer (score 1):

Change the column type to [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).